# View another window during slideshow

Tags: windows, slideshow, powerpoint

I'm trying to view a window while working with the slideshow, but on clicking on slideshow again other window gets minimized. So, How to view another window during slideshow without the slideshow being unaffected?

Answer (score 0):

1. In powerpoint, go to "Slide Show" (or just "Show" depending on your version) at the top menu bar.
2. Then click "Set Up Show....." (or just "Set Up" depending on your version)
3. Under Show type, select "Browsed by an individual (window)" and click OK.

This will put it into a window so you can go back and fourth like you are talking about.

Comment: basically, what i want is, i want an application running in a window(small window) at the right bottom of the slide show. I did by the above method, when i click anywhere on slideshow, the window gets minimized.

Comment: As long as powerpoint is not completely maximized, I am able to click back and fourth between windows without minimization occurring. You still have to be in powerpoint to advanced a slide, so the other window won't be visible while advancing. Alternatively, if you make the powerpoint window smaller then you can click back and fourth without minimization. Your version may be different, and this is not a perfect solution.. I get that.